# Adjust a 100% width image to vertically center using jQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Basically I have a fixed size div that contains an `<img>` tag. I cannot change the structure.

Often these images are much larger than the container due to keeping them 100% width and filling the box. Most times this results in too much of the image shown at top and not cropped to the center of the image.

So using jQuery (or pure CSS if possible) I want to adjust the position of the image to move it up so the top is cropped off instead of the bottom.

Also, this should remain responsive as the viewport changes width.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xecLjhcp/)

```css
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/900/500/">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/901/500/">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable with known height container, like your demo. We can set the container to `position:relative`, and set the image to `position:absolute`, plus some extra set ups as follows.

```css
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/900/500/">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/901/500/">
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph2vdh6n/1/)**

Comment: Yeah that's true. The container is fixed height but I was also thinking I needed to know the height of my image but you really don't. I was confusing that simple problem with the container height.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using the images as the div background, you can do the following:

**Option1:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="first"></div>
<div class="container" id="second"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    border: solid;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#first {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/901/500/');
}
#second {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/900/500/');
}
```

**Update- Option2:**

without using the image as background.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="centered" src="http://placekitten.com/900/500/" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="centered" src="http://placekitten.com/901/500/" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    border: solid;
}
.centered {
    object-fit: none; 
    object-position: center; 
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Please check this [option1](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/xecLjhcp/2/), [option2](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/xecLjhcp/3/)

Comment: Yeah I can't change the structure so I'll check out option 2. Using background images would have been easy but I can't.

Comment: So object-fit is not supported by IE. I found a polyfill and it's an option, but I'm certain a jQuery solution will be leaner than an additional polyfill css and js files and then a javascript function to handle it in the footer.

Comment: Regardless, it's a good answer and in a beautiful world where IE doesn't exist this would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

For now I'm going to use:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    var hHeight = $(this).height()/2;
    $(this).css("top", - hHeight);
});
```

I would love to see other solutions, especially if they are better.